How to close all open trades on current candle when backtesting?
When working with Pinescript v5 in TradingView, how can I close all open trades on the current candle when backtesting? I would like to have a checkbox to activate such a "close all open trades for backtesting purposes" feature and tried several different approaches, but none worked.

try strategy.close_all()
if youCloseAllCondition
    strategy.close_all(immediately = true)


Thanks very much G5tavo71, I forgot to mention that I my close condition is a checkbox that activates this feature, not a time based event in a chart.
